# Where is First-Order Peano Arithmetic first clearly formulated?

Tags: number-theory, mathematical-logic, arithmetic

I really should know this, but ...

When/where/by whom was first-order Peano Arithmetic first clearly and explicitly formulated in a recognizably modern form (perhaps exact notation apart) -- with the usual recursion axioms for successor, addition, multiplication and the schema for induction axioms?

Comment: [Wikipedia's Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) has links to Peirce's 1881 and Peano's 1889 formulations. You'll have to review them and decide if they are sufficiently "clearly and explicitly recognizably modern".

Comment: But the question is whether they are "first order".  As I understand it, Peano's formulation was "second order", since the induction principle was formulated for (in modern language) "all subsets", not merely for subsets expressible as a formula.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar It is hard to tell from the post if this is what "recognizably modern" turns on. One can focus on other distinctions instead, and the OP needs to make clear what it is they are looking for specifically. The conversion of second order axioms into axiom schemas was a technical triviality once FOL got established, and had little to do with arithmetic specifically. If the question is really about the rise of first order logic SE has extensive posts on that already, e.g. [How did first-order logic come to be the dominant formal logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2617/9148)

Comment: See [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598201/peano-arithmetic-before-g%c3%b6del) for a possible source.

Comment: Alonzo Church, IML, fn.524, page 320 gives, in addition to Hilebert&Bernays, some further references: a paper by Hilbert (1928) and one by Ackermann (1940).

Comment: It seems that you can find Hilbert's notes into David Hilbert, [Lectures on the Foundations of Arithmetic and Logic (William Ewald & Wilfried Sieg editors, Springer (2013))](https://books.google.it/books?id=v7YfBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA925), page 925 (Hamburg 1927 lecture) and page 979 (Hamburg 1930 lecture).

Comment: @Conifold Sorry if it wasn't clear enough. Looking for a reference for the possible next edn. of one of my Gödel books, so I'm up to speed on the general background.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It looks like Hilbert/Bernays (so probably Bernays!) is the earliest. I guess it has to be post-Gödel 1931 that people settled on a first-order formulation with just successor, addition, multiplication built in, because it was only after we know the beta-function trick that we know we don't need separate explicit definitions for the other primitive recursive functions (which come for free in the second-order setting).

Comment: @PeterSmith - I agree. Gödel (1931) is till Principia-like: high-order logic as underlying logic but instead of W&R "mathematical" axioms (Reducibility, Infinity) the SOL version of Peano's axioms. As you said, the "prominence" of FOL emerged slowly.

Comment: Two books I have (but don't know enough nor have time now to dive into) that might be worth looking through are [**Perspectives on the History of Mathematical Logic**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0817647686) edited by Thomas Lyndon Drucker (1991) and [**The Search for Mathematical Roots. 1870−1940**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/069105858X) by Ivor Grattan-Guinness (2000). The second almost certainly has everything and more that you want, but trying to distill exactly what you want, and no more, is probably going to be very difficult (which I'm sure you know if you're familiar with G-G's book).

Comment: @conifold: 'first order ... first clearly and explicitly' is not hard to parse. And given that Peter Smith is a logician he will know the difference between first order and second order ...

Comment: @DaveLRenfro - good point! GG has Hilbert-Bernays (1934a), A.Tarski 1933a: ‘‘Einige Betrachtungen uber die Begriffe ω-Widerspruchsfreiheit und der ω-Vollstandigkeit’’, and R.Carnap 135b, 1935b. ‘‘Ein Gultigkeitskriterium fur die Satze der klassischen Mathematik’’

Comment: We have also to consider Herbrand (1930); see van Heijenoort, page 581.

Comment: @PeterSmith Have you looked at Gentzen's papers in which he proves the consistency of PA? I looked at them a while ago and I think this might answer your question. Certainly, in order to give a proof that PA is consistent, one needs to say very precisely what PA is, and Gentzen does this. From what I recall, the way he did it made it sound like he might have been the first one to write it all down completely explicitly.